# I want to retrieve data from database into a livewire Component?

Tags: laravel, database, laravel-livewire

*Hello guys I am trying to retrieve data from my database to a livewire component  and I keep getting this error*:
**Property [destination] does not exist on this collection instance**.

*here is my migration table*:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('delivery_fees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('destination');
        $table->integer('domicile');
        $table->integer('stopdesk');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

*am trying to retrieve the **destination** value like this:

```
public function render()
{ 
    $delivery_fees = DeliveryFee::all();
    dd($delivery_fees->destination);
    return view('livewire.form-elements');
}
```

**Note**
*when I try `dd($delivery_fees)` It show me all the database values but when I try this `dd($delivery_fees->destination)` to retrieve only the destination value it throws back an error.*

**Please feel free to tell me what I am doing wrong and tell me how to fix it. thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
use App\Models\DeliveryFee;

public function render(){
      return view('livewire.form-elements')
          ->with([
          'Delivery_fee' => DeliveryFee::all()
            ]);
 }
```

In the `livewire.form-elements` page you can now access all the columns like this:  `Delivery_fee->destination` and other propoerties in the Table.

Make sure you import the model in `DeliveryFee` in the live wire component

Answer (score 0):

**Hello guys**
*well I just used query builder and the result was like I wanted*

**This is what I have done**:

```
public function render()
{
    $delivery_fees = DB::table('delivery_fees')->select('destination')->get();
    dd($delivery_fees);
    return view('livewire.form-elements');
}
```

**This got me what I wanted using query builder** if there is another way to achive the same result please let me know

Comment: try use `DeliveryFee::query()->select('destination')->get();` OR  `DeliveryFee::query()->get(['destination']);` it's all the same